# import libraries on eclipse 2021 fails Example: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource

Tags: java, eclipse, libraries

I am migrating a Java code that is running on Java 8 and I need to compile it to run on Java 17, so Just downloaded eclipse 2021-09 import the code from Git, change project facet selecting Java, add to Java Build Path the libraries.

[libraries added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKxRg.png)

This is the code:

```
package itksoluciones.avl.lst.dboperation;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;


public class PoolConexionUC {

    public static DataSource dataSourceUC;
    
    public PoolConexionUC() {
        inicializaDataSourceUC();
    }
    
    private void inicializaDataSourceUC() {

        BasicDataSource basicDataSourceUC = new BasicDataSource();
        
        basicDataSourceUC.setDriverClassName(DataConexion.driverUC);
        basicDataSourceUC.setUsername(DataConexion.userUC);
        basicDataSourceUC.setPassword(DataConexion.passUC);
        basicDataSourceUC.setUrl(DataConexion.urlUC);
        basicDataSourceUC.setMaxActive(Integer.parseInt(DataConexion.maxActiveUC));
        
        basicDataSourceUC.setMaxIdle(DataConexion.defaultMaxIdleUC);
        basicDataSourceUC.setMaxWait(DataConexion.defaultMaxWaitUC);
        basicDataSourceUC.setRemoveAbandoned(DataConexion.removeAbandonedUC);
        basicDataSourceUC.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(DataConexion.removeAbandonedTimeoutUC);
        basicDataSourceUC.setValidationQuery(DataConexion.validationQueryUC);
        basicDataSourceUC.setTestOnBorrow(DataConexion.testOnBorrowUC);

        dataSourceUC = basicDataSourceUC;
    }
    
}
```

This are the two errors:

> Import org.apache could not be resolved
> and
> BasicDatasourceCore could not be resolved to a type

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmSRU.jpg)

As you could see from the error the library seems available, also it autocompletes when typing.

Also one of the solutions  suggested by eclipse is to import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource. (after doing it by double clicking on the suggestion first error is resolved but the second one persists).

What is also very curious is that if I copy paste the class PoolConexionCore to PoolConexionCore2. The problem is gone in PoolConexionCore2.

BUT I HAVE MANY CLASSES WITH THE SAME PROBLEM so I really appreciate any suggestion to avoid having to be dedicated to copy pasted for several days.

[After doing copy paste](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQYwF.jpg)

Comment: *add to Java Build Path the libraries* Why are you doing this instead of using Maven or Gradle?

Comment: I usually add the JAR files to the _Modulepath_ (and **not** to the _Classpath_) and I create a [module-info.java](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html) file.

Comment: @chrylis, thanks. . I just move libraries to Module PATH but it did not worked.  Perhaps do you know a way that I can ask eclipse to reload the project or something like that?  As I have uploaded this from repository I may be missing telling eclipse what kind of project is this.   I am not using Maven or Gradle because this is a code I did about 6 years ego and I was not familiar with that, I am still a newbie on this.

Comment: @chrylis, many thanks!.  Situation is resolved. Working on this I did a change in the route for a file config, save it. But I noticed execution keeps with the old config file, so I discovered that changes were not really getting to eclipse environment.  So I deleted everything. and redo the process, this time I clone GIT REPO, and then I imported this as eclipse project. then I went to project explorer and load the libraries and everything was working PERFECTLY.    I had forgot to import the git clone as eclipse project. I think that was the error.